# Parse pipe seperated string (Pipes can be escaped ) in Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing, escaping, tokenize

Receive a pipe separated parameter, need to tokenize it; but pipes can be escaped with \| to indicate its not a seperator, but part of the token. I know the Java compiler does this with strings we have " and escaped quotes \" in a string literal.

But not sure of a good utility function/ algorithm to tokenize such a string. Output will be a List of strings.

Sample Input 1: `"jk|g4"`, output : `"jk" , "g4"` (list with 2 strings)

Sample Input 2: `"j\|k|g4|b"`, output : `"j|k" , "g4", "b"` (list with 3 strings and literal pipe)

Tried using `String.indexOf("|")`, then checking the previous character if its a \ ... but have errors and wanted to make sure : is there is an easier way? Regex?

Here is what I have :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PasrePipes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String in = "j\\|k|g4|b";
        {
            String[] ex = { "j|k", "g4", "b" };
            tst(in, ex);
        }

        in = "j|k|g4|b";
        {
            String[] ex = { "j", "k", "g4", "b" };
            tst(in, ex);
        }
    }

    private static void tst(String in, String[] ex) {
        System.out.println("----\n" + in);
        List<String> toks = parse(in);
        if (toks.size() != ex.length) {
            System.out.println("size mismatch, got :" + toks.size() + " exp " + ex.length);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.length; i++) {
            if (toks.size() > i) {
                String n = toks.get(i);
                if (!ex[i].equals(n)) {
                    System.out.println(" mismatch :" + i + ", got :" + n + "; exp :" + ex[i]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" okay :" + i + "; exp :" + ex[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("--");
    }

    private static List<String> parse(String in) {
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = in.indexOf('|');
        int old = 0;

        while (i > -1) {
            if (i > 0) {
                if (in.charAt(i - 1) == '\\') {
                    i = in.indexOf('|', i + 1);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            String s = in.substring(old, i);
            s.replace("\\|", "|");
            tokens.add(s);
            old = i + 1;
            i = in.indexOf('|', i + 1);

        }
        if(i > 0 && i < (in.length() - 1)) {
            String s = in.substring(i + 1);
            s.replace("\\|", "|");
            tokens.add(s);
        }
        return tokens;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and the errors you are getting.

Comment: @tgkprog: I assume you actually mean `"j\\|k|g4|b"`, since `"j\|k|g4|b"` is not a valid string literal in java. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: added what i have @jim-garrison

Comment: yes i was taking input from a form so put what you would see in a text box ... but yes in code need to escape the \ @Syon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is not a big matter you could try following pidgin way:

```
//replaces all escaped pipes to a temporary replacement
string = string.replaceAll("\\\\\\|", "tmpReplacement");

//iterate through all parts of the string which is divided by a pipe
for(String str : string.split("\\|"))
{
     str = str.replaceAll("tmpReplacement" , "\\|"/*or how you need it*/);
     //now you can use str; str is each part of the variable string, which has not been escaped
}
```

Comment: tmpReplacement is the input ?>

Comment: No, input is the variable string. "tmpReplacement" is just a string literal used for ignoring the escaped pipes. Later they are beeing replaced by the correct one again.

Comment: Thank you @user2088127 :-) will  do a few more tests (works for the two samples i have )

Comment: No problem, if you get your tests fail, just ask. If they not fail, I would appreciate an accepted answer ^^

Comment: thank you very much :) im new here and need some reputation, sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do both a split and replace with a single regex statement. But you can split using a negative look behind:

```
(?<!\\)[\|]
```

And then replace `\|` with `|`

```
String value = "j\\|k|g4|b";
String[] split = value.split("(?<!\\\\)(\\|)");
for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    split[i] = split[i].replaceAll("(\\\\\\|)", "\\|");
    System.out.println(split[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
j|k
g4
b
```

**Update**

Do note though that this won't work if you're escaping a slash directly before the pipe.

```
String value = "j\\\\|k|g4|b";
...
```

Output:

```
j\|k
g4
b
```

Desired output:

```
j\
k
g4
b
```

Because Java does not support variable length look-behind, there's no way to split the string on the delimiter. You can however use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` to match against every field with an even number of slashes before the delimiter.

```
String value = "j\\|k|g4|b|kjbk\\\\\\|\\ml|jbkjbjk\\\\\\\\|k\\jb\\k\\\\\\j|m\\\\\\|\\\\kb";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(([^\\\\](\\\\\\\\)*\\\\\\|)|([^\\|]))+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
while(matcher.find()){
    String field = matcher.group().replaceAll("(\\\\\\|)", "\\|");
    fields.add(field);
    System.out.println(field);
}
```

Output:

```
j|k
g4
b
kjbk\\|\ml
jbkjbjk\\\\
k\jb\k\\\j
m\\|\\kb
```

Comment: @tgkprog: Are you sure about that? Works with that input for me. Can you point to an online regex tool that produces the same failure?

Comment: using java 7 copied your code, but instead of just printing added to a list in loop : tokens.add(split[i]); i do not think the online tools use java internally. probably a java bug :( and works in python or php

Comment: it works, yes i forgot to change value :) duh i upvoted your answer but since both work accepted the one with less points

Comment: @tgkprog, you can find online testers for just about any regex flavor.  For Java regexes I usually use [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: @tgkprog: Forgot about the case where you may be escaping a slash directly before the pipe. Added a solution for this as well.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with regex (as Syon demonstrated), but it looks too complicated and error prone. I find this simple function a lot better solution:

```
/*
 * Parses a delimited string with an escape character 
 */
public static List<String> parse(String s, char delimeter, char escape){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean escaped = false;
    for(char ch : s.toCharArray()){
        if(escaped){ 
            sb.append(ch);
            escaped = false;
        }
        else {
            if (ch == escape){
                escaped = true;
            }
            else if(ch == delimeter){
                result.add(sb.toString());
                sb.setLength(0);
            }
            else{
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
    }

    result.add(sb.toString());

    return result;
}
```

You call it like this:

```
parse("j\\|k|g4|b", '|', '\\')    // --> [ "j|k", "g4", "b" ]
```

Comment: the performance is optimal, because each character is visited only once and you have to visit all character - it's the same as or better than any regex solution

Comment: Great, thanks I accepted the other guy's answer but this does looks great too. +1